# PHP: make user specific request after login

Tags: php, html, security, authentication

I am struggling in my mind with a little problem.

So, a user tries to log in. If the username and password are correct, he will redirected to a dashboard. I will set some Session variables like userid and username.

- First questions: can these variables be manipulated? I would like to show the username who is logged in. Can I use this from the Session variable or do I need to fetch it always from the database?

Next, when he logged in a user should only view his private pictures. I have a PHP request which returns the image files in a JSON. It works good. But how can I make it secure and save?

- What parameter should I post to that JSON? Just posting a userid from the Session variables? But what if someone tries to call that PHP and just changes the userid? He will get pictures from someone else? How can I make sure, that the person who makes the request, is really the person?

Thanks in advance. I am really interested in this topic, I would love to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First questions: can these variables be manipulated? I would like to
>   show the username who is logged in. Can I use this from the Session
>   variable or do I need to fetch it always from the database?

Displaying from the session is usually enough, but yeah, you can manipulate it.

> What parameter should I post to that JSON? Just posting a userid from
>   the Session variables? But what if someone tries to call that PHP and
>   just changes the userid? He will get pictures from someone else? How
>   can I make sure, that the person who makes the request, is really the
>   person?

Send the user id in the request. Then, in the back end, check if that id is the same as the id of the current logged user. If it is, return the image, if not, return an error. That's how you can make it safe.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good way. But for the second answer, if the session variables can be manipulated, is it really safe?

Comment: They can be manipulated by you, in the code, that's what I meant XD

Comment: The user shouldn't be able to manipulate them. I mean, there are some attacks and no system is 100% secure, but you can use session variables with no problems.

Comment: Thank you Lucas. Very good answer. So I will just make a request with a id, check if the id matches with the session id and I am ready to go.

Comment: Thanks. Really interested in that topic. Looking forward to learn more. Not sure why I get so many downvotes, but the answer was worth it.

Answer (score 1):

First questions: can these variables be manipulated? I would like to show the username who is logged in. Can I use this from the Session variable or do I need to fetch it always from the database?

> First of all, Set the userid in session and retrieve the data based on
>   that `userid`. It would be secure to use a global variable for login
>   such as :  `$_SESSION["is_login"] = true;`
>
> Please validate first if `userid` and `is_login` both exists then your
>   page should move further else it must show an error.

Next, when he logged in a user should only view his private pictures. I have a PHP request which returns the image files in a JSON. It works good. But how can I make it secure and save?

What parameter should I post to that JSON? Just posting a userid from the Session variables? But what if someone tries to call that PHP and just changes the userid? He will get pictures from someone else? How can I make sure, that the person who makes the request, is really the person?

> You should pass the encrypted `userid` or `is_login` to url and validated
>   it to check it whether it is true? else use a default image instead of
>   user's image

Comment: Thanks, but what if userid and is_login gets manipulated? I can still get that image. I just set userid to a id and is_login to true?